# Authentication Error in using Alfresco Rest API

Tags: rest, authentication, alfresco

I am trying to hit the alfresco rest api using my standalone rest code. i get the login ticket when i use the below url -

```
"http://host:port/alfresco/service/api/login?u=admin&pw=admin"
```

and i got the ticket but how do i use this ticket for further communication with alfresco without facing this authentication problem.

below is the code i am using for communicating with the alfresco rest client.

```
HttpGet getReq = new HttpGet(url);
getReq.addHeader("accept", "application/json");
StringEntity input = new StringEntity(args);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(getReq);
```

Kind Regards
Garvit Jain

Comment: Where is your authentication error ? Please edit your title if you are not facing an error.

Answer (score 2):

Append the alf_ticket argument to your URL and pass in the ticket you retrieved from the /api/login call. See http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Web_Scripts#Authenticating

Comment: Hi Jeff,

Thanks, now i am trying with the below URL -

    http://localhost:9080/alfresco/service/api/search/keyword.atom?q=Morgan_Stanly?alf_ticket=TICKET_ddb2e4e6d1d12bc88bbe9006766750ce090e3c42

and i got the below response - 

    HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized [Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1, WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Alfresco", Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8, Content-Length: 951, Date: Mon, 20 May 2013 04:21:11 GMT]

please advise.

Thanks

Comment: When i hit the same url from firefox rest client it is working fine. url - http://localhost:9080/alfresco/service/api/search/keyword.atom?q=Morgan_Stanly?alf_ticket=b1958f7a05da228dd120a75e1dfdbd5093f82c61  Responce - 

    Status Code: 200 OK
    Cache-Control: no-cache
    Content-Type: application/atom+xml;charset=UTF-8
    Date: Mon, 20 May 2013 04:33:24 GMT
    Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
    Pragma: no-cache
    Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Comment: In your Firefox REST client it looks like you are sending "application/atom+xml" as the content-type header, which is correct. Is that the same you are sending with your rest code?